# What is the typical convention for importing Java packages?

Tags: java

In my programming classes in college, we would just import an entire package even if we just used one class from it. This may have been because we were supposed to use IDEs that did not offer autocompletion or anything fancy like that, so it would just make it easier to code in general.

However, now that I'm more of an experienced programmer, is it more conventional to import Java packages as a whole or just the classes from those packages that you would need?

For example, instead of:

```
import java.util.*;
```

Is it conventional to say:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
```

etc.?

Does importing an entire package compared to select classes use more memory?

Answer (score 5):

It's not so much a memory issue, but rather that you run the risk of inadvertently importing the wrong class if you use the * notation.  Generally it's not a problem, but if the * matches a class that you meant to pull in from another package it's a hard bug to find.

I've seen IDE's use the rule that specific class imports are replaced by a single '*' import statement if you're importing three or more classes from that package.  I prefer to call out each imported class by name.

Answer (score 3):

This Wildcard type-import-on-demand declarations as you have given like `import java.util.*;` must NOT be used directly in code; use only required class name instead like `import java.util.ArrayList;`

The following and many other reasons are there:

- The important reason is that a new unexpected class file can be  added to the same package.  This new class can conflict with a type you are using from another package, thereby turning a previously correct program into an incorrect one without touching the program itself.
- Explicit class imports clearly convey to a reader the exact classes that are being used (and which classes are NOT being used).
- Explicit class imports provide better compile performance. While type-import-on-demand declarations are convenient for the programmer and save a little bit of time initially, this time is paid for increased compile time every time the file is compiled.

For more regarding coding conventions refer: http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html#

Comment: That second bullet point is very important:  Explicit imports tell other people exactly what classes your code is using, rather than making those people guess.  Thus, they make the code easier to read.  When you write code professionally, there is a 100% chance that someone else eventually will need to maintain your code; readable code is a mark of professionalism because it saves people time which saves companies money.

Comment: @VGR Actually, it does not tell you anything about the classes which are really being used by your code (although it is a hint); you cannot rely on this because: **1.** you can import classes which are NOT being used at all, and **2.** you can use fully qualified names for classes in code, in which case you need not use the `import` statement.

Comment: @proskor: You are technically correct, however. 1) The IDE can issue warnings for this occurrence.  2) Most professional programmers use fully qualified names in the code **if and only if** there's a class conflict.  java.awt.Image and org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image was the last class conflict I had to deal with.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Although your critique is sure valid, I disagree with the comment made by VGR in general, especially regarding the statement that the `import`s tell other people *exactly* what classes are being used in your code. I have never looked at the imports of a source file just to determine its dependencies (I guess this makes me 'unprofessional' ;)), but the reason for that is that it wouldn't help me to do my job better in any way (I simply could not see the forest for the trees). What I *do* look up, however, is the list of imported packaged in the OSGi-manifest, for example.

Comment: By the way, even if You would look at the `import`s, what's the point of knowing that, for example, a class is using `javax.swing.JPanel`, but not `javax.swing.JButton`? Doesn't it suffice to know that it does some Swing GUI stuff, in which case an `import javax.swing.*` would be just enough? I cannot think of a case in which such detailed information would be in some way useful...

Answer (score 1):

Often, memory consumption will be similar, as the class you import will probably end up using other classes in the same package due to inheritance and functionality logic.

In my school (high school junior year), they currently make us import the entire package. This is mainly due to the fact that our IDE (BlueJ), offers the bare minimum of auto complete, and hence it'd be quite a pain to have to hand import every single class we use.

Personally though, I use Eclipse and IDEA for my work, and import each class manually. This prevents conflicts between same names classes in different packages, which is a great help to me since Android has equivalent classes for a lot of the Java framework, but in a different package.

Answer (score 0):

From the performance point of view, there is a slight overhead when compiling, but no difference during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

@Chris Gerken has a good point.

But it is not just bugs.  Wild-card imports can lead to problems if you recompile against an updated library that (in the new version) adds a new class with the same name as one you are already using.  So wild-card imports tend to make your code more fragile in the long term.